# Android Activity Intent Filter, Action View and Category Default

Tags: android, intentfilter

I was looking at sample android applications, and I noticed all of the activities in the manifest had:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I noticed that my activities start fine without this intent-filter. So what is the point of this intent-filter and is it best to include them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<intent-filter>` has to be given for atleast the first activity which you want to start in your application.

The lines :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

if given to an activity, then its purpose is to enable the user to interact with the activity that is either `VIEW` or `EDIT` or `INSERT`.

`DEFAULT` category is required for all filters except for those with `MAIN` action and `LAUNCHER` category

It is not necessary to give the `<intent-filter>` to every activity, but as said in the developer's guide it would be a better practice to use.